# How do I handle this?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

Let´s see some code to explain better:
I made a request to a WS as showing bellow:

```
        $idERP = 1;
        $grupoEcota = new \SoapClient($url);
        $paramExtrato = array(
            'sGrupo' => $request->sGrupo,
            'iCota' => $request->iCota,
            'iIdERP' => $idERP,
        );
        $responseExtrato = $grupoEcota->ROS_ExtratoContaCorrente($paramExtrato);
        $grupoEcota = $responseExtrato->ExtratoContaCorrente;
```

I get a response from a WS witch looks like this from dd(die and dump):

```
$dados[] = $grupoEcota->{'PARCELAS-PAGAS'};
        dd($dados);

array:1 [▼
  0 => {#784 ▼
    +"PARCELA-PAGA": array:21 [▼
      0 => {#783 ▼
        +"NUMERO-PARCELA": 48
        +"DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20170818"
        +"DATA-PAGAMENTO": "20170919"
        +"VALOR-PARCELA": 580.28
        +"HITORICO-PARCELA": ""
        +"PERC-PAGO": 3.491
      }
      1 => {#771 ▶}
      2 => {#781 ▶}
      3 => {#780 ▶}
      4 => {#779 ▶}
      5 => {#778 ▶}
      6 => {#777 ▶}
      7 => {#776 ▶}
      8 => {#775 ▶}
      9 => {#774 ▶}
      10 => {#773 ▶}
      11 => {#772 ▶}
      12 => {#757 ▶}
      13 => {#770 ▶}
      14 => {#769 ▶}
      15 => {#768 ▶}
      16 => {#767 ▶}
      17 => {#766 ▶}
      18 => {#765 ▶}
      19 => {#764 ▶}
      20 => {#763 ▶}
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get only the first "DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20170818" item. How do I do it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you are dealing with an array, lets fetch that first element out (my assumption is there will only be one element.).

```
$data= $data[0];
```

Now we have a key value array, we can now fetch out the `PARCELA-PAGA`.

```
$parcels = $data{'PARCELA-PAGA'];
```

Multiple objects in a array is the next level, this means that there are in each object data, so i would use array_pluck to get these elements out.

```
$vencimento = array_pluck($parcels, 'DATA-VENCIMENTO');
```

If you do not care about multiple data fields, you could simply take the first element. Be careful this data is not an array, but an object.

```
$vencimento = $parcels[0]->DATA-VENCIMENTO;
```

Which should result in a result looking like this.

```
[""20170919"", "20171019", ...]
```

Comment: I´ve added some more code to show you guys what I need. Need to get only the very first ' DATA-VENCIMENTO ' because there´s a different file to download depending on the day of payment.

Comment: I had a part of my question, that addressed that problem "$vencimento = $parcels[0]->DATA-VENCIMENTO;", if you have any problems please describe them, it seems fine for now since you accepted?

Comment: Not really. But your answer made me decide to paste more code to explain better. I still have an issue to get 'DATA-VENCIMENTO`value.

Answer (score 0):

Got the help of a friend:

```
$firstRecord = collect($dados[0]->{'PARCELA-PAGA'})->firstWhere('DATA-VENCIMENTO', '20170818');

dd($firstRecord);
```

then...

```
{#783 ▼
  +"NUMERO-PARCELA": 48
  +"DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20170818"
  +"DATA-PAGAMENTO": "20170919"
  +"VALOR-PARCELA": 580.28
  +"HITORICO-PARCELA": ""
  +"PERC-PAGO": 3.491
}
```

And I finished doing:

```
dd($firstRecord->{'DATA-VENCIMENTO'});
```

I got "20170818" which is the value I'm looking into. I think it solves the problem! Thanks, dude, you are the man!